# Levi-Civita type Connection?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let's assume $M$ is a real smooth manifold. Also, let $E$ is complexified Tangent Bundle $TM^c$ equipped with a hermitian metric structure. Then $E$ has complex Hermitian vector bundle structure.

> Is there any notion of compatiblity of the hermitian structure and linear connections on vector bundle $E$?

what is this compatiblity interpretation?